# visual basic. the syntax error is in insert into

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Me.firstswim.Text = "" Or Me.lastswim.Text = "" Or Me.yearswim.Text = "" Or Me.addressswim.Text = "" Or Me.contactswim.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please fill-up all of the textbox! ", , "Error!")
    Else

        Try
            OpenDB()

            Dim sql As String = "INSERT into Swimming (FirstName,LastName,Year/Course,Address,ContactNumber) VALUES (@FirstName,@LastName,@Year/Course,@Address,@ContactNumber)"
            Dim cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", Me.firstswim.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", Me.lastswim.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year/Course", Me.yearswim.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Me.addressswim.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNumber", Me.contactswim.Text)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Save Success")
            Return
            LoadSwimming()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            closeDB()

        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This happens when you use bad names for columns.  you will have escape `Year/Course` everywhere it appears: `[Year/Course]` or change the name to something better

Answer (score 0):

Identifiers in SQL can only consist of alphanumeric characters (and underscores), so you cannot have a slash '/' character in a name.

Column names (and other object names) in a database can have other characters in them, but their names must be escaped in square-brackets `[]` (T-SQL and Access) or `` ` `` backticks (MySQL) or double-quotes `"` (PostgreSQL):

Parameter names and variable names in T-SQL cannot be escaped and must be alphanumeric.

change your code to:

```
INSERT INTO ... LastName, [Year/Course], Address ... @lastName, @yearCourse, @address ...

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yearCourse", Me.yearswim.Text)
```

Comment: it's still the same syntax error.....i changed everything from Year/Course to YearCourse including the field name of it in my database....

Comment: @RamFrancia What database system are you targeting?